# drools DRL classpath resource

Tags: grails, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I have a grails app with an XMLSolverFactory, loading it's XML configuration file from ./myapp/grails-app/conf/ with the code below. It cannot find the DRL file from the same path though. How can I get an XML configured Solver to find a classpath .DRL resource if it's running in a container?

```
def InputStream stream = this.getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream("nurseRosteringSolverConfig.xml")
solverFactory.configure(stream);
```

The configuration XML snippet

```
<scoreDrl>nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
```

throws the error

```
scoreDrl (nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl) does not exist as a classpath resource
```

Answer (score 0):

The getClass() code might prefix the package of your class.

Suppose your class file is in package org.foo.bar and your nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl is also in that package, then you 'd write:

```
<scoreDrl>/org/foo/bar/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
```